# Uncertainty of the couple position-kinetic energy

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Let's suppose we have a quantum system that consists of a free particle on the real line. The Hilbert space associated to this quantum system is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Let $x$ and $p$ be the position and momentum operators. The operatorial version of Schrodinger equation states that if the system is in a state $\psi=\psi(x)$ then

$$\sigma_\psi(x)\sigma_\psi(p)\geq \frac12 |\langle \psi,[x,p]\psi\rangle|$$

It's pretty easy to see that $\langle \psi,[x,p]\psi\rangle=0$ iff $\psi=0$, but $\psi$ can't be $0$, so there is no state in which the uncertainty of $(x,p)$ can be reduced to $0$.

What if we try with the couple $(x,p^2)$. This is trickier because:

$$\langle \psi,[x,p^2]\psi\rangle=0 \iff \langle \psi,\psi'\rangle=0$$

I understand that $\psi'$ can't be $0$, but why does this imply that $\langle \psi,\psi'\rangle$ can't be $0$ for any $\psi$? I think that $\psi(x)=e^{-x^2}$ does the job! Right?

Comment: Right. More generally, if $\psi(x)$ is an even (odd) function of $x$, then $\psi'(x)$ is an odd (even) function of $x$, hence $\langle \psi,\psi'\rangle=0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo We've proved that in the state $e^{-x^2}$, the uncertainty of the couple position-kinetic energy is $0$. So in this state we can measure position $x$ and kinetic energy $K$ with arbitrary precision. But since $p=m\sqrt{2K/m}$, doesn't this imply that we can also measure the position and the momentum of the particle in the state $e^{-x^2}$? Isn't this contradictory?

Comment: No, you certainly did not prove that for this Gaussian state the dispersion of position-kinetic energy vanishes, as worked out explicitly in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are misconstruing the uncertainty principle, because I didn't understand your argument. I am a little baffled by why you failed to directly compute the uncertainty of your Gaussian state, (basically the ground state of the oscillator),  bypassing generic Robertson inequality [jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Mathematical_formalism). Nondimensionalize  ℏ=1, *m*=1.

For the state $\psi= N e^{-x^2}$ where $ N^2=\sqrt{2/\pi}$, you have, directly, the variances
$$
\sigma_\psi ^2 (x)= N^2\int\!\!dx~ x^2 e^{-2x^2}= 1/4, \\
\sigma_\psi ^2 (p^2/2)= N^2\int\!\!dx~ e^{-2x^2}(4x^2-12x^2 +3) -\left ( N^2\int\!\!dx~ e^{-2x^2}(2x^2-1) \right )^2\\ 
=3/4-1/4=1/2,
$$
where I hope you have recognized the Hermite polynomials controlling the problem here, so that
$$
\sigma_\psi  (x)  \sigma_\psi  (p^2/2)= \sqrt{2}/4.
$$

It is not evident what "trick" you are invoking, but, for that state, the precise uncertainty is nonvanishing.